# What's the difference between Item and Class<Item>

Tags: haxe

Assuming we have

```
class Item {}
```

What's the difference between `Item` and `Class<Item>`?

Actually, what `Class<Item>` means and how it's supposed to be used?

Answer (score 2):

You have some explanation of this in the [Haxe manual](http://haxe.org/manual/types-class-instance.html).

`Item` is the type of the instances of the class in the code block you have posted. `Class<Item>` is the type of the class itself. It is a bit confusing, but is a common concept present in other OO languages like Java, too.

The utility of `Class<Item>` is to query *in runtime* for the methods or fields in a class. This is usually called [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)), and is useful in many particular contexts like [metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming), [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) or [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), among others. There is a [page in the Haxe manual](http://haxe.org/manual/std-reflection.html) dedicated to reflection, too.

Answer (score 0):

After some playing I came to something like this example to understand.

```
class Main {
    static function main() 
    {
        var item = createItem(Item);
        var item2 = createItem(Item2);
        var dupItem = duplicateItem(item);        
        var dupItem2 = duplicateItem(item2);
    }

    static function duplicateItem(item:Item):Item
    {
        trace('Duplicate ' + item);

        var itemType = Type.getClass(item);        
        var item:Item = Type.createInstance(itemType,[]);         
        return item;
    }

    static function createItem(itemType:Class<Item>):Item
    {
        trace('Create ' + itemType);
        var item:Item = Type.createInstance(itemType,[]);  

        return item;
    }
}

class Item
{
    public function new ()
    {
        trace("Item 1");
    }
}

class Item2 extends Item
{
    public function new ()
    {
        super();

        trace("Item 2");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Main.hx:23: Create [class Item]
Main.hx:34: Item 1
Main.hx:23: Create [class Item2]
Main.hx:34: Item 1
Main.hx:44: Item 2
Main.hx:14: Duplicate [object Item]
Main.hx:34: Item 1
Main.hx:14: Duplicate [object Item2]
Main.hx:34: Item 1
Main.hx:44: Item 2
```